# Using Proxy Webservice with Adobe AIR/BlazeDS

Tags: apache-flex, air, blazeds

I am trying to call a webservice using proxy. My settings for  proxy-config on blazeds side are as below:

```
<destination id="ws-catalog">
    <properties>
        <wsdl>http://feeds.adobe.com/webservices/mxna2.cfc?wsdl</wsdl>
        <soap>*</soap>
    </properties>
    <adapter ref="soap-proxy"/>
</destination>
```

On Adobe AIR side, my code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="loadConfiguration()">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.messaging.ChannelSet;
            import mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            [Bindable]
            private var cs:ChannelSet;

            private function loadConfiguration():void
            {
                var amfChannel:AMFChannel = new AMFChannel("my-amf", 'http://localhost:8400/messagebroker/amf');
                cs = new ChannelSet();
                cs.addChannel(amfChannel);
            }

            protected function ws_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var obj:Object = event.result;
            }

            protected function ws_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
            {
                var faultObj:Object = event.fault;
            }

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                ws.getOperation('getFeeds').send();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:WebService id="ws" 
                      channelSet="{cs}"
                      useProxy="true" 
                      destination="ws-catalog"
                      showBusyCursor="true"
                      result="ws_resultHandler(event)"
                      fault="ws_faultHandler(event)"
                      />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button label="CallWebService" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

But now, whenever I launch my AIR app, am getting following error:

```
faultCode: InvokeFailed
faultDetail: Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (null)
faultString: [MessagingError message='Destination 'ws-catalog' either does not exist or the destination has no channels defined (and the application does not define any default channels.)']
```

Can somebody help me OR point me to a similar solution?
Thanks.

Comment: When you use the BlazeDS as a proxy for the Web Service, probably you should use `RemoteObject` on the Flex side not `WebService`

Comment: Am not sure.. as I said, any pointer foe proxy webservices using RemoteObject/Webservice would help to understand.

Comment: I tried using RemoteObjects using same destination and I ended up with "The 'HTTPProxy' service can only process messages of type 'HTTPMessage'." error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code below. It works on my machine. You need to wait a couple of seconds, getFeeds returns a lot of data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.messaging.ChannelSet;
        import mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.soap.LoadEvent;
        import mx.rpc.soap.mxml.*;
        import mx.rpc.wsdl.WSDLOperation;
        [Bindable]
        private var cs:ChannelSet;
        [Bindable]
        var gateway:WebService

        private function loadConfiguration():void{
            var amfChannel:AMFChannel = new AMFChannel("my-amf", 'http://localhost:8400/samples/messagebroker/amf');
            cs = new ChannelSet();
            cs.addChannel(amfChannel);
            gateway = new WebService();
            gateway.channelSet = cs;
            gateway.destination = "ws-catalog";
            gateway.useProxy = true;
            gateway.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,ws_resultHandler);
            gateway.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,ws_faultHandler);
            gateway.loadWSDL();
        }

        protected function ws_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
            var obj:Object = event.result;
            trace("ok");
        }

        protected function ws_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void{
            var faultObj:Object = event.fault;
            trace("nok");
            trace(faultObj);
        }

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            gateway.getFeeds();
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button label="CallWebService" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

Comment: It is working when I do it in script block (as you mentioned above). But as soon as I specify destination in mxml, it somehow throws the fault error straightway. I am using Parsley for some DI and Probably it is the reason as my channels are being loaded at a later point after applications creationcomplete. Anyhow, thanks..I am able to reach my webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing all the configuration. You can check a couple of reasons like:

-failure to declare the proxy-config.xml file in services.xml

-failure to include services.xml in the project

-failure to declare a channel for your destination

The best way to learn how to invoke webservices using BlazeDS as a proxy is to download the [blazeds turnkey installation](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?event=custom&sku=FS0001561&e=lc_blazeds) and to take a look at the samples. After uncompressing the archive you can find the samples folder in blazedsrootfolder/tomcat/webapps/samples. You will find one example showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using the same blazeds turnkey installation and the destination that I am using ws-catalog is the one that comes along with blazeds. The only thing about turnkey package is that none of the samples describe this proxy-config usage using client side. I have put this client side code here. If any modifications needed to client side, please advise. Thanks.